# Kentico | Mega Menu Query

Tags: kentico

I have setup a basic mega menu following steps outlined [here](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/creating-a-mega-menu-using-hierarchical-transformations)

All works fine except for a couple issues:

1. I can only get image to display in menu if I hardcode img src link i.e. MenuItemTeaserImage won't work even using all four variations of the following: (note: I uploaded a teaser img to form tab for relevant page also)

> ```
> <img src="<%#GetFileUrl("MenuItemTeaserImage")%>" alt="" />
>
> <img src="<%# GetImage("MenuItemTeaserImage", 200, 200, 100, "image alternate text") %>" alt="" />
>
> {%MenuItemTeaserImage.ToString()==""?"":"<img src='~/getattachment/" + MenuItemTeaserImage + "/" + DocumentName + "?maxsidesize=20' style='margin: 0 5px 0 0; float: left;' />"#%}
>
> <%# IfEmpty(Eval("MenuItemTeaserImage"), "", "<img src='" +GetFileUrl("MenuItemTeaserImage") + "?maxsidesize=20' style='margin: 0 5px 0 0; float: left;' />") %>
> ```

2. My sub sub pages in menu appear beside sub pages but I want them to fall below them as per normal mega menu convention. I tried creating another tier in tree hierarchy with same settings as tier level 1 (from same article) but no joy?

[image]

You can see from img that menu teaser img not displaying and 'cafe test subpage' appears left of 'Cafe test' even though its a subpage of it and likewise 'Cafe sub subpage' appears after 'North America' even though it is a subpage of that menu item.

Appreciate any help to above issues and particular based on the fact I used procedure from this [article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/creating-a-mega-menu-using-hierarchical-transformations)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The MenuItemTeaserImage is an attachment so you can call the GetAttachmentUrl or GetFileUrl methods to retrieve the url or GetImage to get the image directly.

Answer (score 0):

Also, looks like you used direct upload of image file to be stored in database as binary file data. You could used "Text" data type and "Media selection" form control to pick an image stored in media library. Then the Eval("MenuItemTeaserImage") will return you the URL to the image directly.